# how would I transfer dataGridView data from one form to another?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I currently have a dataGridView in a form, it has 3 columns (Name, Power, Duration) which I can populate with different values.

I want to be able to transfer these values into ideally a comboBox (failing that another dataGridView) on another form, at the click of a button.
So far i've only managed to open a second form...

Any input would be appreciated

```
private void buttonDrawChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 MyForm = new Form2();
    MyForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: DataGridView is a two-dimensional table, while ComboBox is a simple one-dimensional list. What values do you need to show inside the ComboBox? Or do you want to create one ComboBox per column?

Comment: Will we need more code to help you.  I can give you a hint though...The DataGridView needs to be public

Comment: To extend what @Physikbuddha said, -or does each `DataGridViewRow` represent an object (with those 3 columns as properties)? In which case, it's just a matter of choosing which property will be displayed in the `ComboBox`.